# how to change kernel optimization level?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I use kgdb for kernel debugging and I have a problem with printing values.

I wanted to get information about parameters of function. (ex (gdb) p *page)
But all I got was **optimized out**

I found that it happens due to compiler optimization. And they says changing kernel optimization level to Og would help.

But I don't know how to change it.

I changed toplevel Makefile like below.

```
703 ifdef CONFIG_CC_OPTIMIZE_FOR_SIZE
704 KBUILD_CFLAGS   += -Os
705 else
706 KBUILD_CFLAGS   += -Og                                                                                                                                                                                          
707 endif
```

But, I got error during make.

```
scripts/Makefile.build:497: recipe for target 'fs/cifs' failed
```

Comment: Drop your changes. Enable `CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y`. Study *lib/Kconfig.debug* for more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you want Og level for kernel, check it out here. In the early days I have sent such patch serias but rejected by Linus.

kernel hacking: GCC optimization for better debug experience (-Og)

https://lwn.net/Articles/753639/

Comment: Hi. I found your article before uploading this question, but I don't know how to apply your patch. It would have been nice if that CC_OPTIMIZE_FOR_DEBUGGING has been applied.